# How would I fix my CSS Link Property onClick with Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the color of a link after it is clicked and then set back to its original color when another link is clicked. To do this I want to set a class "active" and then remove it when another link is clicked.

How do I fix my code for it to run properly?

```js
$(function() {
  var links = $('a.link').click(function() {
    links.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
a.link.active {
  background-color: #000033;
  color: #FFFFCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Hyper Links</li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/bp4nv12s/

Comment: Is your question how to restrict this only to the links in the `<ul>`?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to restrict it just to the ul links

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
enter code here
<script>
      $(function() {
               var links = $('a.link');
               $(document).on('click','a.link',function(e){
                     links.removeClass('active');
                     $(this).addClass('active');
            })
     });
</script>
```